# Launchpad as a Space on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, spaces

I was wondering if it's possible to make Launchpad a space?

Just like how you can get the Dashboard to show as a space *(System Preferences -> Mission Control -> Show Dashboard as a Space)*.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I think you're out of luck. While Launchpad appears in the Applications folder and Dock like a normal application, it's really more of a built in OS feature. You can't make it full screen or assign it to it's own space like a normal app.